# trying to filter secret list with tag1key:tag1value AND tag2key:tag2:value

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk

These filters almost work, but they don't actually require that the key  and the value are together and the docs are inscrutable to me.

```
lsi := &secretsmanager.ListSecretsInput{
        Filters: []types.Filter{
            {
                Key:    "tag-key",
                Values: []string{"env_id"},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-value",
                Values: []string{environment},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-key",
                Values: []string{"rds_credential_type"},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-value",
                Values: []string{"app_readwrite"},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-key",
                Values: []string{"rds_instance"},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-value",
                Values: []string{instance},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-key",
                Values: []string{"rds_database"},
            },
            {
                Key:    "tag-value",
                Values: []string{database},
            },
        },
    }
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'm baffled

Comment: So what your question/issue?